# Element removal via ng-if is delayed when using ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

Element removal from the DOM with ng-if or ng-show is delayed when ngAnimate is injected into the app, this does not occur otherwise.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rPTjsDCcgGpg6xfS0IVP

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You've probably got a CSS transition somewhere around the element / classes in question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is happening in the semantic.css that you are including.

Comment: This does not occur if ngAnimate is not injected. If you remove ngAnimate you will see that it functions as expected with or without semantic-ui.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a workaround hack to make it work, but if your wrap your buttons in a `<div></div>` with the ng-if on the wrapper then it will immediately load. https://plnkr.co/edit/PGZgrKzZHO7GSCkwfP23?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the `semantic.min.css` file. Remove that line and you no longer see the flickering (of course, you don't get styling either). What this means is that semantic-ui is adding some transitions that are being picked up by ng-animate.

In fact, it looks like the `ui` class is causing the problem. Remove that class and the flickering goes away as well (as does the styling).

This in itself is not a lot of help, but it does point to the problem being with the intersection of angular and semantic-ui.